# ArcGIS Pro 3.1 errors out on lidR sf object Hulls exported as a polygon shapefile

Tags: r, arcgis-pro, sf, lidr, rgdal

So I am trying to write a `Hulls object` created from the `crown_metrics` function to a shapefile using `st_write`. Now, with `st_write` to resolve the `3D` error in regards to a shapefile, I first used `st_zm`.

Now `st_write` exports the hulls as a shapefile just fine without any errors. But, when I try to import the shapefile into `ArcGIS Pro` I get Error 000731: `The file either does not exist or the file is not supported.

Then I try exporting the `Hulls` using `writeOGR` and that also fails as it returns:

```
inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE
```

How can I fix this?

```
Code:

library(sf)
library(lidR)
library(rgdal)

# Drop the Z coordinates
Silva_Hulls_zm = st_zm(Silva_Hulls)

# Write as a shapefile
st_write(Silva_Hulls_zm, "path/Silva_Hulls.shp", delete_layer = TRUE) # Fails to import to ArcGIS Pro

# Export using GDAL
writeOGR(obj = Silva_Hulls_zm, dsn = "path/Silva_Hulls.shp", layer = "path/Silva_Hulls.shp", driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = T)
```

**UPDATE**
I was able to solve the `writeOGR` error by converting the `sf` object an `sp` object. However, the polygon shapefile still fails to import to `Pro`.

Now as a workaround I uploaded the same polygon Hulls shapefile as a Zip file to ArcGIS Online and it uploads and displays just fine in `MapViewer` as shown below. So in a way I am able to bring it to ArcGIS Pro through ArcGIS Online.

[image]

So I am guessing there's some sort of a conflict with the way sf/rgdal export polygon shapefile and how `Pro` reads it.

Comment: Is it only a problem with `Pro` or other software have difficulties at reading it? Can `QGIS` read it? Cam `sf` read it? It seems to be a problem with `Pro` only according to your description.

Comment: @JRR good morning and thank you for the quick response :). Unfortunately, I don't have access to QGIS on my work computer. But yeah, `st_read` imports the exported `st_write` `Hull shapefile` just fine.

Comment: So I can't help. Maybe you should just share the file and ask what's wrong with the file to ArcGIS specialized people.